# Prove $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{c_{d-1}}{z}+\frac{c_{d-2}}{z^2}+ \cdots + \frac{c_0}{z^d}\right)$=1

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Fix $c_0, c_1, \cdots, c_{d-1} \in \mathbb C$. Prove $$\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{c_{d-1}}{z}+\frac{c_{d-2}}{z^2}+ \cdots + \frac{c_0}{z^d}\right)=1$$
It seems stupid since I think we can just write it as
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{c_{d-1}}{z}+\frac{c_{d-2}}{z^2}+ \cdots + \frac{c_0}{z^d}\right) & =\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}1+\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}\frac{c_{d-1}}{z}+\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}\frac{c_{d-2}}{z^2}+ \cdots + \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}\frac{c_0}{z^d}\\ &=1+0+\cdots +0\\
& =1
\end{aligned}$$
But I am not sure whether I missed something here since it is a problem in the textbook...Thanks for any advise.

Comment: You have it correct.

Comment: What @MarkViola wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful here since a complex number has a real and an imaginary part. What should $z\to\infty$ say? Consider the following sequences:
$$
a_n=n+ni,~b_n=n-ni,~c_n=-n+ni,~d_n=-n-ni.
$$
Which of these sequences goes to infinity? But we can go further an consider a rotating sequence like $e_n=n\cos\left(n\frac\pi8\right)+n\sin\left(n\frac\pi8\right)$. Is here $e_n\to\infty$?

My point is, that for real limits, you can easily understand $\infty$ as *extrem large* because the reals are ordered. But there is no order on the complex plane, so $z\to\infty$ has to be used very, very carefully!

I'm actually sure that the textbook considers the limit $z\to\infty$ in sense of $|z|\to\infty$ and we have to use this to prove the statement.

Now let us prove

> Fix $c_0, c_1, \cdots, c_{d-1} \in \mathbb C$, then
>   $$\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{c_{d-1}}{z}+\frac{c_{d-2}}{z^2}+ \ldots + \frac{c_0}{z^d}\right)=1.$$

First, we consider that is is sufficient to prove
$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{c_{d-1}}{z}+\frac{c_{d-2}}{z^2}+ \ldots + \frac{c_0}{z^d}\right)=0.
$$
Using the rules for existing limits, we can deduce the statement.

Further, there should be a theorem or lemma in your textbook which says:

> *Lemma:* If $\lim_{z\to a}|f(z)|=0$ then $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=0$.

So we observe
$$
0\leq\left|\frac{c_{d-1}}{z}+\frac{c_{d-2}}{z^2}+ \cdots + \frac{c_0}{z^d}\right|
\leq \frac{|c_{d-1}|}{|z|}+\frac{|c_{d-2}|}{|z|^2}+ \ldots + \frac{|c_0|}{|z|^d}.
$$
This implies
$$
0\leq\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\left|\frac{c_{d-1}}{z}+\frac{c_{d-2}}{z^2}+ \cdots + \frac{c_0}{z^d}\right|
\leq \lim_{|z|\to\infty}\frac{|c_{d-1}|}{|z|}+\frac{|c_{d-2}|}{|z|^2}+ \ldots + \frac{|c_0|}{|z|^d}.
$$
On the RHS we can substitude $x=|z|$ and get a real limit, which is obviously $0$. We deduce
$$
\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\left|\frac{c_{d-1}}{z}+\frac{c_{d-2}}{z^2}+ \cdots + \frac{c_0}{z^d}\right|=0
$$
and using the above lemma we get further
$$
\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\left(\frac{c_{d-1}}{z}+\frac{c_{d-2}}{z^2}+ \cdots + \frac{c_0}{z^d}\right)=0
$$
and are done.

Complex limits can be similar to real limits, but you have to be more precise!

Comment: Mundron Schmidt, how is my answer please?

Answer (score 2):

Your limit is equivalent to
$\lim_{z \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^d \dfrac{c_{d-k}}{z^k}
= 0
$.

If
$|z| >1$,
then,
by the triangle inequality,

$\begin{array}\\
|\sum_{k=1}^d \dfrac{c_{d-k}}{z^k}|
&\le \sum_{k=1}^d |\dfrac{c_{d-k}}{z^k}|\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^d \dfrac{|c_{d-k}|}{|z^k|}\\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^d \dfrac{|c_{d-k}|}{|z|}
\qquad\text{since } |z^k| \ge |z|\\
&\le \dfrac1{|z|}\sum_{k=1}^d |c_{d-k}|\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$|z|
\ge \max(1, \dfrac1{\epsilon}\sum_{k=1}^d |c_{d-k}|)
$,
$|\sum_{k=1}^d \dfrac{c_{d-k}}{z^k}|
\le \epsilon$.

Comment: marty cohen, how is my answer please?

Comment: As has been commented, you assumed that the sum of the limits is the limit of the sum. This is not necessarily true. The use of the triangle inequality  makes this rigorous.

Comment: ayt thanks! $ \ $ good to know I had a right feeling